# setting selectedindex of html.dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a dropdownlist in my asp.net MVC2 view like this:

```
 foreach (var whiteout in Model.Whiteouts)
        {  
 <%= Html.DropDownList("drprepeat", new SelectList(Model.RepeatList))%>
}
```

I want to make drprepeat's one item selected based on value of whiteout.field. How can I do this ?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it using:

<%= Html.DropDownList("drpFields", new SelectList(Model.Fields, "FieldID", "NiceName", whiteout.FieldID)) %>